# How to remove dummy packages?

Tags: updates, update-manager, stable-release-updates, update-alternatives

I have searched and I believe there is no a question like this one. Whenever my laptop finds updates the *`Software Updater`* application comes up as usual however it is always showing the package highlighted in the picture (both with the square and the cursor).

I'm unable to check them, nor update them. Is there a way of updating them or delete them?[image: Software Updater]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was solved by using `synaptic` and double clicking the package `libapache2-svn` (which had a exclamation mark in the status (S) column, meaning: "installed and upgradeable").

The package got updated - problem solved.

I don't really know why it wouldn't update using the update manager.

Answer (score 0):

Do:`sudo apt-get remove libapache2-svn apache2.2-bin`, then, before confirming, check carefully that no packages are removed that you want to keep.
The lines in your screenshot are taken from the *Description* field in the package database. You can search for keywords with `apt-cache search keyword`.

Comment: It asks me if I want to remove wine gecko, and I don't want to. So what now? if I hit yes it will be removed if I hit no it will be aborted.

Comment: Strange. Your dependencies have been messed up. Maybe it will just go away after an update. Alternatively, using `aptitude why`, find out why you are holding these packages.

Comment: Thanks man, I solved using other method, check my answer if you want.